# Adding text to a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm creating a tape measure in a `UIScrollView`, it has horizontal lines from an image and I want to add the numbers programatically.

(Note the blue was to help getting the layout right)

[image: tape measure]

I tried this:

```
 for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.maxUnits.integerValue; i++) {
        static CGFloat labelWidth = 40;
        CGFloat x = (halfScreen - (labelWidth/2)) + (i * self.widthOfOneFraction.floatValue * self.numberOfFractions.floatValue);

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x-1, 41, labelWidth, 70);

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor tlbBlueColor];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0];
        [self addSubview:label];
    }
```

Which works, but uses about 40Mb of RAM. I thought that adding the text in a CATextLayer might be more efficient, but I can't get it working:

```
 for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.maxUnits.integerValue; i++) {
    CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    [label setFont:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"];
    [label setFontSize:20];
    [label setFrame:frame];
    [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    [label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [label setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [self.layer addSublayer:label];
}
```

The numbers don't appear on the screen.

So my question is can I either make the first way more efficient, and if not is the second way more efficient when it works and if so how do I get it working?

Comment: I would hope you could generalize your implementation to something like a horizontal table view.  You could easily reuse those numbers as they scroll onscreen rather than brute forcing them all into the view hierarchy at once.

Comment: I wondered about making it only actually draw say 3 times the width of the screen and then redraw as it swipes, but as you can scroll really fast this might degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way the loading worked so as to only load items on display and to load a few more as you scroll.

This seems to have totally fixed the high memory issue and even if you scroll to both ends it doesn't use the same high amount of memory. I guess there was a leak in how my original code worked.